# Stat.exists false with list of variables in ansible

Tags: arrays, ansible

**UPD:** (As advised @vladimir-botka)

I have a problem with checking NOT existing folder using dictonary in Ansible.

```
---
- name: "check folder"
  hosts: "myserver"
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    git_repos:
     repo1:
        git_repo_folder: /var/www/folder1
     repo2:
        git_repo_folder: /var/www/folder2

  tasks:

  - name: "1. Check that the folder exists"
    stat:
      path: "{{ item.value.git_repo_folder }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', git_repos) }}"
    register: check_folder

  - name: "2. debug"
    debug:
      msg: '{{item.item.item.value.git_repo_folder}} exists'
    with_items: "{{ check_folder.results }}"
    when: not item.stat.exists
```

Then, if I trying to run playbook, I got the error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'item'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/reset/ansible-prod/SSL-GENERATOR/TEST.yml': line 22, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: \"2. debug\"\n    ^ here\n"}
```

**UPD2:**

I've tried to debug it:

```
- debug: var=check_folder and got:

ok: [myserver] => {
    "check_folder": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_label": {
                    "key": "repo1", 
                    "value": {
                        "git_repo_folder": "/var/www/folder1"
                    }
                }, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1", 
                        "follow": false, 
                        "get_attributes": true, 
                        "get_checksum": true, 
                        "get_md5": null, 
                        "get_mime": true, 
                        "path": "/var/www/folder1"
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "key": "repo1", 
                    "value": {
                        "git_repo_folder": "/var/www/folder1"
                    }
                }, 
                "stat": {
                    "exists": false
                }
            }, 
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_label": {
                    "key": "repo2", 
                    "value": {
                        "git_repo_folder": "/var/www/folder2"
                    }
                }, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1", 
                        "follow": false, 
                        "get_attributes": true, 
                        "get_checksum": true, 
                        "get_md5": null, 
                        "get_mime": true, 
                        "path": "/var/www/folder2"
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "key": "repo2", 
                    "value": {
                        "git_repo_folder": "/var/www/folder2"
                    }
                }, 
                "stat": {
                    "exists": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where I am wrong? Is it possible to use **"not stat.exists"** with list of variables?

Thanks for answer!
Thanks for answer!
Thanks for answer!
Thanks for answer!
Thanks for answer!

Comment: Take a look at *-debug: var=check_folder*. Post it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's test non-existence, because the folders do not exist. The task below

```
- name: "2. debug"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.item.value.git_repo_folder }} does not exist"
  with_items: "{{ check_folder.results }}"
  when: not item.stat.exists
```

gives:

```
"msg": "/var/www/folder1 does not exist"
"msg": "/var/www/folder2 does not exist"
```

Comment: `when: not item.stat.exists` take the same error:
`The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: I make as You said. Can You please get advice?

Comment: You have one *item* too much in *item.item.item.value.git_repo_folder*. See updated answer.